# How to make an object planar and remove overlapping faces

Tags: objects, 2d

I'm new with blender, I need transform a 3d object to 2D from top view, so I've used in object mode that keyboard sequence  <kbd>S</kbd>,  <kbd>Z</kbd>,  <kbd>0</kbd> so I have a flat surface as I want but with many overlapping faces on it.

How i remove/merge all overlapping faces to get only perimeter and lowest number of faces?

[image]

Comment: what exactly is what you need? Can you show us some pictures? If you don't care about topology or other things and only want to view you could just scale it with 0.001 for example and faces won't overlap.... If you want to make it 0, you will need to tweak that topology manually if vertices don't overlap as well

Comment: done as u can see there are alot of faces overlapping

Comment: i'm not sure there's any way to fix that, as MikoCG says, maybe tell a bit more why you need to do this? there may be a way around